# Selecting data from database based on date

Tags: php, mysql, regex, date, select

hope you fine and well,

i have a table that contains persons information and i have a registration date column in the table, i want to to fetch the registered people in specific date.

to be more specific i want to enter some date in html input then to select from database based on this date.

i tried two solutions but they failed actually:

1. by entering the full date : this will work just with full date, for example if i entered 2016-1-1 i will get the results of this date, but if i want to return all the people who registered in 2016-1 or 2016 my query will fail since these values are not equal the dates in the table !
2. using regular expression, its okay but it will fail again ! if i entered 2016-1 for example , the query will return the results of 2016-11 also !

so any ideas ?! or any better regular expressions ?!

regards.

Comment: Try `REGEXP '[[:<:]]2016-1[[:>:]]'`, or - if the date is the only column value - `REGEXP '^2016-1[[:>:]]'`

Comment: thanks, but i want a general expression used with php variable ($date) , which is the entered date !

Comment: Then please show the code you tried that failed.

Comment: SQL LIKE Operator would come in handy here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: @devofash , thanks dear , it seems the best solution until now . really ranks.

Comment: No problem @msmc good luck!!

Comment: Why did you input the date as a string? If you put it as a date object, your life will be much easier

Comment: thanks, but how this will help ?! @AminahNuraini

Comment: Don't use varchar for dates.  Use leading zeros on month and day (`'2016-01-01'`).

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to do it in the query, in my opinion at least.

So you want all users from 2016?

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE year(`date_field`) = '2016'; 
// Where 'date_field' is the name of your date field
```

Or 2016/01 would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE year_month(`date_field`) = '2016-01'; 
// Where 'date_field' is the name of your date field#
```

Or you could use this for 2016/01:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE year(`date_field`) = '2016' AND month(`date_field`) = '01'; 
// Where 'date_field' is the name of your date field
```

For a full list of MySql date functions check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: thanks dear, but i need a general solution, the user will input any date he want in php variable ! for example: 2015-11 , 2004-05-06 , 2009 and so on !

Comment: So in your html script give the user a form to select said date. Then in your PHP script build the query using the values provided by the user. Like this --> http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Comment: nice idea ! but it fails with dates like 2009-05 ! if you keep day filed empty the form will say : Invalid Date !

Comment: Why would you store an invalid date? That is a serious data storage flaw. You trying to circumvent normal behavior, is making your own life harder, for no long term gain? However you could always, not validate the form and if the day is left blank fill it from your script with a 01. Though far from recommended.

Comment: no dear, i dont want to store dates from the html input ! i will take the entered date from the input and then i will select data from database based on this date, when i keep day filed empty this means that i want all registered people in specific month , for example i want all registered users in 2009,April ! so the input date will be 2009-04 .

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you can also query for results between certain dates.

What i often end up doing is:

```
// For a certain month or period
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE date_field >= '2016-01-01'
AND date_field <= '2016-02-01';

// For a whole year
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE date_field >= '2016-01-01';
```